# mean and median calculation problem MIDE-51

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I have an 5×5 matrix in the external ram and i want to calculate the mean and median of all the numbers and store only the mean and the median value to another 5×5 matrix in the internal ram. How do i do that? I am very noob in this software and language.

The addition gives a result higher than 255. I don't know how to store it.

Comment: If the result overflows 8-bit storage then use 16 bits or larger.  If you have a specific question about assembly, then show your work and ask about where you're stuck.  FYI, you don't have to think in assembly language to manipulate a matrix, any language can do it.  So, that allows to separate the algorithm issues from assembly issues, which makes things much easier.  Assembly is so much easier when you already know precisely what you want the code/program to do, step by step.

Comment: If your MIDE-51 is the same one mentioned in http://www.opcube.com/home.html, it's a MCS-51  microcontroller, aka 8051 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MCS-51), not 8086 / emu8086.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.